# copy fixed content between two delimeter in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, string, textbox

i want to copy or transfer the fixed words between two delimiting symbols from one textbox to another.i was successful in transferring the single word from one text box to another but when i wanted to transfer two or more word,it showed the error.the transferring of the word happens when the button is pressed.
 My code for transferring single word between the delimiting symbol is:-

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sSource As String = TextBox1.Text 'String that is being searched
    Dim sDelimStart As String = "FirstName=" 'First delimiting word
    Dim sDelimEnd As String = "." 'Second delimiting word
    Dim nIndexStart As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimStart) 'Find the first occurrence of f1
    Dim nIndexEnd As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimEnd) 'Find the first occurrence of f2

    If nIndexStart > -1 AndAlso nIndexEnd > -1 Then '-1 means the word was not found.
        Dim res As String = Strings.Mid(sSource, nIndexStart + sDelimStart.Length + 1, nIndexEnd - nIndexStart - sDelimStart.Length) 'Crop the text between
        TextBox2.Text = res 'Display
    End If
End Sub
```

Above code works properly but when when i wanted to search and transfer two words it showed the error as **ArgumentException was Unhandled** and **Argument 'Length' must be greater or equal to zero**.My error containg code is:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sSource As String = TextBox1.Text 'String that is being searched
    Dim sSource1 As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim sDelimStart As String = "FirstName=" 'First delimiting word
    Dim sDelimStart1 As String = "LastName="
    Dim sDelimEnd As String = "." 'Second delimiting word
    Dim sDelimEnd1 As String = "."
    Dim nIndexStart As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimStart) 'Find the first occurrence of f1
    Dim nIndexStart1 As Integer = sSource1.IndexOf(sDelimStart1)
    Dim nIndexEnd As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimEnd) 'Find the first occurrence of f2
    Dim nIndexEnd1 As Integer = sSource1.IndexOf(sDelimEnd1)

    If nIndexStart > -1 AndAlso nIndexEnd > -1 Then '-1 means the word was not found.
        Dim res As String = Strings.Mid(sSource, nIndexStart + sDelimStart + 1, nIndexEnd - nIndexStart - sDelimStart.Length) 'Crop the text between
        TextBox2.Text = res 'Display
    End If
    If nIndexStart1 > -1 AndAlso nIndexEnd1 > -1 Then '-1 means the word was not found.
        Dim res1 As String = Strings.Mid(sSource1, nIndexStart1 + sDelimStart1 + 1, nIndexEnd1 - nIndexStart1 - sDelimStart1.Length) 'Crop the text between
        TextBox3.Text = res1 'Display
    End If

End Sub
```

I think the error is due to the repeated use of Length variable in 'if' statement but i don't know how to fix that.The link to the snapshot of my desired output is:http://tinypic.com/r/1zy7iwz/8  i was only able to transfer the word harry but not the porter.Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the Split function?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
Example on how to use it:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/split-vbnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, I think you need to add `.length` after your `sDelimStart` and `sDelimStart1`. Currently, you're trying to pass a String + Integer as an Integer.

```
Dim res As String = Strings.Mid(sSource, nIndexStart + sDelimStart.length + 1, nIndexEnd - nIndexStart - sDelimStart.Length)
```

And in your second if statement:

```
Dim res1 As String = Strings.Mid(sSource1, nIndexStart1 + sDelimStart1.length + 1, nIndexEnd1 - nIndexStart1 - sDelimStart1.Length)
```

However, I would recommend using the `String.Split` function:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

EDIT: Why it is displaying same thing in both.

I think this is because you need to find the last index of the delimiters.

```
Dim nIndexStart As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimStart) 'Find the first occurrence of f1
Dim nIndexStart1 As Integer = sSource1.LastIndexOf(sDelimStart1)
Dim nIndexEnd As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimEnd) 'Find the first occurrence of f2
Dim nIndexEnd1 As Integer = sSource1.LastIndexOf(sDelimEnd1)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.it is showing same result in both textboxes,textbox2 and textbox3 like it is printing same name in both the textboxes.how can i solve it.i am not familiar with the split function so please help me solve this problem.

Comment: No problem! Hope we can get this working. See my edit about getting the last index of your delimiters.